# How to find Inverse Kinematics solution to 6 link manipulator planar robot using DH parameters

Tags: robotic-arm, inverse-kinematics, dh-parameters

I want to find out the inverse kinematics solution of 6 link manipulator planar robot, using DH Parameters, but I don't know how to, I know how to calculate for 3 link manipulator but not for 6 links, I found out that we have to use Inverse Transformation Matrices for higher DOF problems but I was not able to find the solution even with those, and I couldn't find any example either, in which they would show how to solve this problem. Can anyone tell me the solution to this problem or provide me with a link to the solution?

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* Vishnu, but I'm afraid that questions which are as broad as this are off-topic because answers would need to be too long. As it says in [ask] *If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much*. We prefer *[practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](http://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*, so please take a look at [ask], [about] and the [*Robotics* question checklist](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1302/37) for advice on writing a good question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is a bit too broad to answer here.  I recommend you find a good robotics manipulation textbook and work through it.  Here are three classics:

- Robotics: Modelling, Planning and Control by Bruno Siciliano, Lorenzo Sciavicco, Luigi Villani, and Giuseppe Oriolo.  Available on [Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1846286417) or [pdf](https://github.com/yangmingustb/planning_books_1/blob/master/Siciliano%20-%202009%20-%20Robotics%20modelling,%20planning%20and%20control.pdf).
- Robot Modeling and Control by Mark W. Spong, Seth Hutchinson, and M. Vidyasagar.  Available on [Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0471649902) or [pdf](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Mohamed-Mourad-Lafifi/post/How_to_avoid_singular_configurations/attachment/59d6361b79197b807799389a/AS%3A386996594855942%401469278586939/download/Spong+-+Robot+modeling+and+Control.pdf).
- A Mathematical Introduction to Robotic Manipulation by Richard M. Murray, Zexiang Li, and S. Shankar Sastry.  Available on [Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0849379814) or [pdf](https://www.in.tum.de/fileadmin/w00bws/i23/murray-li-sastry-94-complete.pdf).

But there are many others on the topic.  I prefer the first book by Siciliano et al.  Note that the last book by Murray et al uses a different formulation for kinematics.  They use Product of Exponentials instead of DH Parameters.